# Typescript: Trying to make this dictionary of dictionaries work

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary of other dictionaries work but just work "sometimes".
I have this dictionaries that i call "books" in each of them there are a group of objects of the same model.

So I turn this arrays of  objects of the same model into this "books"/dictionaries and then I gather the books inside a "library"/dictionary.

The idea is being able to access every book from the same place like:
"library.book[object key]"

When I console log the whole library every book is there..

> Object {  }
> ​
> education: Object {  }
> ​​
> : Object { … }
> ​
> experience: Object { "L&A Construcciones": {…}, Aegis: {…}, test123: {…}, … }
> ​
> matt: Object { id: 1, first_name: "Rodrigo", last_name: "Luna", … }
> ​
> projects: Object { test: {…}, "this is another test": {…}, "yet another test": {…} }
> ​
> skills: Object {  }
> ​
> : Object { … }
> app.component.ts:88:12

..but when i try to access a book(or console.log it) gives me a error that says that the book is  undefined.

Im totally missing the problem and i need some help

Edit. This is a part of the complete code.
So It works like this on init first calls a get"book" that gets the data from a spring data base. This data comes as an array. So in gatherMuseLibrary i turn this array into a dictionary object and put it inside another dictionary using the "bookName" as the key and then i access the book inside of museLibrary to make some arrays that i need for another part of the programm. This part as no trouble at all. I can actually access the books at this point and make the arrays like "codingSkills".

The problem is when i call "getSubjects". When i console.log the whole library inside of "getSubjects" there is no problem, i can see every book. But when i try to access each book to get some info the books are undefined. And I'm using the same method to access the books that in the get"Book" with "keys()".

I hope this helps :/

````
codingSkills: Array<SkillModel> = [];
writingSkills: Array<SkillModel> = [];
lifeSkills: Array<SkillModel> = []; 

//Muse Needs
museLibrary: {[key: string]: {[key: string]: any}}= {};

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSkills();
    this.getSubjects();
}
getSkills(){
    this.skillService.getAllSkills().subscribe(data =>{
      this.gatherMuseLibrary("skills", data)
      if (this.museLibrary.skills !== undefined){
        for (let key of Object.keys(this.museLibrary.skills)){
          let skill = this.museLibrary.skill[key]
          switch(skill.type){
            case "Coding": this.codingSkills.push(skill); break;
            case "Writing": this.writingSkills.push(skill); break;
            case "Living": this.lifeSkills.push(skill); break;
          }
        }
      }
    })
}
gatherMuseLibrary(bookName: string, data: any){
    const book: {[key: string]: any} = {};
    for (let element of data){
        book[element.name] = element;
    }
    this.museLibrary[bookName] = book;
}
getSubjects(){
    console.log(this.museLibrary);
    console.log(this.museLibrary.skills);
    for (let bKey of Object.keys(this.museLibrary)){
        console.log(this.museLibrary[bKey])
        let book = this.museLibrary[bKey];
        console.log(book);
        for (let key of Object.entries(book)){
            let value = book.key
            console.log(`${key} -> ${value}`);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE, so we can work on the problem directly.  Right now `this.museLibrary` is not defined, and your type `data: []` means `data` is always an empty array, which is presumably not what you intend.  Also you should comment the code exactly where the error occurs and what the text of the error is, so we're all on the same page.  You might want to review the guidelines for [ask] and what a [mre] is.  Good luck!

Comment: `Object.entries` is likely what you want in for inner loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: I just added some more code and an explanation of how everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

This loop doesn't work, unless you define an iterator on your book objects (which doesn't seem to be the case)

```
  for (let key of obj){}
```

Try to `console.log(this.museLibrary[bKey])` to make sure the book is being saved correctly.

Comment: When I try to console.log(this.museLibrary[bKey]) it tells me that is undefined. But in the previous line i can console.log(this.museLibrary) just fine.

Comment: Did you print Key also?